# Remote Windows Docker containers from a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, jenkins, containers

I have a Jenkins CI host server running on Linux machine and a Jenkins build node running on a Windows server. I'd like to start use the Docker containers for building, testing, packaging, and related artifact generation.

However, at the end of the day, I need to generate Windows binaries. Is it possible to create Windows Docker containers on a Windows server and connect to them on a Linux server?

Comment: Like Doc Brown said, "If you put your mind to it, you can accomplish anything."

Comment: Well, that's profoundly unhelpful. Inspiring, but unhelpful. Thank you for the inspiration though.

Comment: I believe this question may be too broad.  I'm not sure how to answer it beyond saying, "Yes, but it will be a mess of mixed VMs/containers".  You can use the [windowsservercore](https://store.docker.com/images/windowsservercore) image, but only on a Windows machine, to build the binary which means your CI would have to issue commands to a Windows machine to build and then do deploy.

Comment: @Zero298, that's already what I do now but without using Docker. The Jenkins master on Linux connects with the Jenkins build node on Windows. Linux Jenkins issues commands to the Windows Jenkins machine, where it builds it, and sends the artifacts back to Linux Jenkins for archiving and possible deploying. I'm hoping to use the windowsservercore image to build and test. What I don't know is if it's possible to connect and mount data to a windowsservercore running on a windows server and connecting to it from a Linux machine. I've really only use Docker on Linux so far.

Comment: Are you trying to connect and mount the storage from your Linux box to your Windows node?

Comment: @sxm1972 yeah. Is that possible? Or is it only possible to mount volumes local to the Docker host?